# css direct-child selector chooses all childs at all levels

Tags: html, css, list, html-lists

this css code should only color the background of li tags directrly under the topUl, but it colors the background of all li in the whole unordered list:

```
ul.topUl > li {
    background-color: #ff0 !important;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: CSS and HTML don't have any kind of children that are not direct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, you haven't change the background colour of the descendant `li` elements from the default of `transparent`.